# Can Google Dataflow generate Parquet files

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, parquet

Can Google Dataflow generate Parquet files as the output of an ETL transformation.

Input  --->  Dataflow   ----->  Parquet files

Answer (score 4):

Cloud Dataflow has supported writing Parquet since `parquetio` was introduced in [2.10](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12319527&version=12344540) in February 2019.   From the [docs](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.15.0/apache_beam.io.parquetio.html)

```
with beam.Pipeline() as p:
  records = p | 'Read' >> beam.Create(
    [{'name': 'foo', 'age': 10}, {'name': 'bar', 'age': 20}]
  )
  _ = records | 'Write' >> beam.io.WriteToParquet(filename,
  pyarrow.schema(
      [('name', pyarrow.binary()), ('age', pyarrow.int64())]
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Dataflow does not have a built-in way of generating Parquet files, but based on a quick look at the [Parquet API](https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/parquet/hadoop/ParquetWriter.java), it should be relatively easy to implement a [custom file-based Dataflow sink](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/custom-io#creating-sinks) doing that (see "FileBasedSink" there).